# Creation of UIButton inside UITextfield

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextfield

i am new to ios development.I want to create UIButton inside UITextfield.When we click on UIButton Uidatepicker appear and when we select date from datepicker the date should display in UitextFiels.I know all logics except insert UiButton inside Uitextfield and Giving action to it.Can any give me the idea.

Thanks, in advance

Comment: Should it be possible to type in the date or should it only be possible to select the date with the date picker? In the latter case fibnochi has given the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you without using UIButton. Use UITextField's delegate methods for this. 
in`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`return NO and show datePikcer
and when datepicker dismises set the text for UITextFiled. for reference have  look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Answer (score 0):

No need of inserting UIbutton in UItextfield. Place uibutton over uitextfield. Just u need to give the same frame for both textfield and button and Make the button as custom button.

Answer (score 0):

Add UIButton instance after adding UITextField. the frame of UIButton should be inside the UITextField frames. keep it mind when you add subviews add UIButton after the UITextField adding.